# Woman adopts a feral child

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

This is a short story I probably read in *Asimov's Science Fiction* in the late 1980s or early 1990s. A woman spots a feral child in a parking lot of an office building - feral children in this universe being almost as common as feral cats in ours - and in spite of the stories she's heard about the dangers (sure, they're cute when they're little, but they grow up to be dangerous) she lures it into her car and takes it home to care for.

I don't remember what happened next, but I suspect that it wasn't all sunshine and roses. I believe she has other children of her own, or a neighbor worried about the danger to her own children.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you might be off on the timeframe, because this sounds like "[Wild Child](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?81675)" by Sharon N. Farber (writing as S.N. Dyer) in *Asimov's*, March 1998.

A bit from the beginning that sets the background for the feral children:

> Life went on. I saw other feral children in the garage, there or at other hospitals, skulking in corners and scampering away. The city put out traps occasionally, but we all knew how miserable the homes were, and didn't encourage catching the kids. Poor little things, abandoned during the critical periods for development of reason and language and socialization, doomed never to develop the skills of humanity. Stunted by malnutrition and neglect. If left alone, they seldom survived long—the few that did make it to adolescence, usually in the far south where winters weren't too bad, became menaces and could be shot on sight. How many mothers said to their kids, "Change those clothes and comb your hair, do you want a cop to think you're feral?"
>
> If caught, they were like wild animals, as dangerous to themselves as to others. Likely to bite off your hand, or to chew off their own in order to escape. So they had to be drugged to the point of semi-coma and tube fed, and usually died fairly soon of pneumonia or blood clots.

The protagonist is a doctor, who sees a child one day, and then again six months later and starts feeding him.  He becomes tamer, but the doctor doesn't take him home, one of the nurses does.  (The doctor's family wouldn't accept a feral.)  The story actually ends on a reasonably happy note.

Comment: Thank you.  In spite  of my misrememberings, this is clearly the right piece.